# 16.04 installing GNOME, getting "Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages"

Tags: apt, gnome, upgrade, package-management

I am trying to install GNOME in Ubuntu 16.04 but I get

```
Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I searched for this and tried to `sudo apt-get update` and upgrade, autoremove, clean, all those commands, but it's not working.

[image: its getting like below]

I also tried using aptitude to install GNOME but it didn't install well.

How can I fix it?

Comment: I already tried the above answer but it didn't work to me. please share any other link

Comment: **Sunil** Please [edit] your question and provide the errors you had while executing from that Q&A...

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this issue only once before, and I solved it with the command `sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get autoclean && sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get update --fix-missing && sudo apt-get upgrade`

Comment: I have tried but it getting again